# Bug when deleting unsaved entity

Tags: breeze

I think I've found a bug when you add a child entity to another entity and then mark the child entity as deleted (Without saving changes previously).

Here is the test:

```
test("delete unsaved entity", 1, function () {
    var realEm = newEm();
    //ok(realEm.hasChanges() === false, "The entity manager must not have changes");
    var query = EntityQuery.from("Customers")
        .where("CustomerID", "==", "729de505-ea6d-4cdf-89f6-0360ad37bde7")
        .expand("Orders");
    stop();
    realEm.executeQuery(query)
        .then(function (data) {
            var cust = ko.observable(data.results[0]);
            var newOrder = realEm.createEntity("Order", {}, breeze.EntityState.Detached);
            cust().Orders.push(newOrder);
            //ok(newOrder.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() === true, "The entity is Added");
            newOrder.entityAspect.setDeleted();
            //ok(realEm.hasChanges() === true, "The entity manager must have changes? Not clear to me but it's true");
            realEm.saveChanges();
            ok(realEm.hasChanges() === false, "The entity manager must not have changes");
        })
    .fin(start);
});
```

Comment: What is the use case for this? Probably better off moving this to an issue in the GitHub project rather than a question on Stack Overflow. https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/issues

Comment: The use case may be:
Add order lines to an order and click an icon to remove a line before saving. I'll fill an issue. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of breeze v1.0.0 this bug is now fixed. Sorry for the delay

### Old post below

Thanks for the repro, **it really helps**.  There is a bug here and it will be fixed in the next release probably later today or early tomorrow.

Just to be clear the bug is that the 'hasChanges' call after the 'setDeleted' call should return false, but currently returns true.  The reason is that deleting an 'added' record simply detaches the entity from the entityManager; hence reverting the entityManager to the state it was in before the 'add'.  The detach does occur, but the hasChanges function is broken in this case.

Two other issues though.

First, you can replace this line

```
 var cust = ko.observable(data.results[0]);
```

with this

```
 var cust = data.results[0];
```

because Breeze will automatically create ko observables out of any entity returned from a query.

and second your call to saveChanges

```
  realEm.saveChanges();
  ok(realEm.hasChanges() === false);
```

needs to be converted to a promise, because saveChanges is asynchonous.

```
  realEm.saveChanges().then(function(r) { 
      ok(realEm.hasChanges() === false);
  }
```

Comment: Just to be clear the bug is that the 'hasChanges' call after the 'setDeleted' call should return false <-- That is the behaviour that i expected. Thx.